# Discount for group of users in Kentico?

Tags: kentico

am new in Kentico and am working on project that will be like E-book store want to ask if there is any way to make **Group of users** and assign discount for them like 10% on all purchase or something i notice that i can assign discount on product level as [Kentico Discount Doc](https://docs.kentico.com/display/K9/Discounts) but this is not my desire .. i just want to create group of users and assign them all discount i think in making it as a role but i don't think it will work like that .. any one has idea?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you can create an order discount and specify for which user role the discount will be available. https://docs.kentico.com/display/K8/Working+with+order+discounts#Workingwithorderdiscounts-Addingorderdiscountstargetedonselectedcustomers

Also you can use macro rules for configuration https://docs.kentico.com/display/K81/Configuring+discount+rules

Or you can create a custom ShoppingCartInfoProvider and check a user role, if it's correct, you will add discount to an order.